# Mantener valores en cajas de texto

Tags: php, html

Estoy iniciando en esto de PHP y he creado este pequeño formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

siempre que le doy al calcular limpia las cajas de texto, funciona OK, pero quisiera que no se limpie las cajas de texto.

Este es mi HTML.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Evaluación Aplicativa</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtApli" id="txtApli" size="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Examen Parcial</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtParcial" id="txtParcial" size="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Examen Final</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtFinal" id="txtFinal" size="3"></td>
  </tr>
```

Este es mi PHP.

```
 <?php
  if (!empty($_POST)){

  $Apli = $_POST['txtApli'];
  $Parcial = $_POST['txtParcial'];
  $Final = $_POST['txtFinal'];

  if (empty($Apli)){
  echo "Ingrese el porcentaje de Evaluación Aplicatica<br>";
  $valida = false;
  }
  if (empty($Parcial)){
  echo "Ingrese el porcentaje de Examen Parcial<br>";
  $valida = false;
  }
  if (empty($Final)){
  echo "Ingrese el porcentaje de Examen Final<br>";
  $valida = false;
  }
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma que se me ocurre para conseguir eso es que el valor de los inputs sea una cadena vacía o 0 (depende de lo quieras o necesites) si todavía no se ha enviado el formulario o ese campo está vacío, y si se ha enviado y tiene valor, como lo guardas en una variable, haces que el input tenga el valor de esa variable. Aquí tienes un ejemplo en el que también te he cambiado la forma de enviar el mensaje de error.

HTML:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Evaluación Aplicativa</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtApli" id="txtApli" size="3" value="<?php echo (!empty($Apli)) ? $Apli : ""; ?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Examen Parcial</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtParcial" id="txtParcial" size="3" value="<?php echo (!empty($Parcial)) ? $Parcial : ""; ?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Examen Final</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="txtFinal" id="txtFinal" size="3" value="<?php echo (!empty($Final)) ? $Final : ""; ?>"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> 
  </form>
  <p><?php echo (!empty($mensaje)) ? $mensaje : ""; ?></p>
```

PHP:

```
    if (!empty($_POST)){

  $Apli = $_POST['txtApli'];
  $Parcial = $_POST['txtParcial'];
  $Final = $_POST['txtFinal'];
  $mensaje;

  if (empty($Apli)){
  $mensaje = "Ingrese el porcentaje de Evaluación Aplicatica<br>";
  $valida = false;
  }
  if (empty($Parcial)){
  $mensaje = "Ingrese el porcentaje de Examen Parcial<br>";
  $valida = false;
  }
  if (empty($Final)){
  $mensaje = "Ingrese el porcentaje de Examen Final<br>";
  $valida = false;
  }
  }
```

Lo he probado por si acaso y funciona perfectamente.